# Java(client) and C#(Server) TCP Socket. and Server read infinite last data from client

Tags: java, c#, sockets, tcp

Java(client) and C#(Server) TCP Socket. and Server read infinite last data from client(Java)
I has been search for entire day already, its weird.

I created 2 client: Java(real), C#(for testing)
like this:

Java(Real):

```
Socket socket = new Socket(SyncActivity.ip,SyncActivity.port);
DataOutputStream out;
out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
String s = "Hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$";
out.write(s.getBytes(),0,s.getBytes().length);
out.flush();
s = "Yes this another data$";
out.write(s.getBytes(),0,s.getBytes().length);
out.flush();
socket.shutdownInput();
socket.shutdownOutput();
socket.close();
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

and
C#(for testing)

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
clientSocket.Connect("192.168.0.138", 11838);
NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

On C#(testing) side, sent one data to server, and server readed the data once and blocked to wait another data.(second data same as reading it once and blocked)I just want like this.

On Java(Real)side, sent two data to server and server reading 1st data once and read same 2nd data forever. Java side is verified sent only once.

It is full data I was received. Why? its weird.

> result as:

on C#(testing)

> Client request connection.
>
> Server accept and created connection.
>
> Server try Read (and Blocked)
>
> Client send >> TextBox
>
> Server received >> TextBox
>
> Server try Read (and Blocked)

but on Java(Real):

> Client request connection.
>
> Server accept and created connection.
>
> Server try Read (and Blocked)
>
> Client send >>
>   Hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> Server received >>
>   Hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> Client send >> Yes this another data
>
> Server try Read
>
> Server received >> Yes this another data
>
> Server try Read
>
> Server received >> Yes this another data
>
> Server try Read
>
> Server received >> Yes this another data
>
> Server try Read
>
> Server received >> Yes this another data
>
> Server try Read
>
> Server received >> Yes this another data
>
> Server try Read
>
> Server received >> Yes this another data
>
> (and forever and forever)

Server code:

```
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt16(Ini.IniReadValue("About", "ServerPort", "MVS_VAN.info")));
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    serverSocket.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    serverSocket.Start();
    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
    serverSocket.Stop();
    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[128000];
    do
    {
                        Socket soc = clientSocket.Client;
                        soc.Receive(bytesFrom);
                        string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                        MessageBox.Show("", dataFromClient);
                        networkStream.Flush();

                    //networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    //string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    //dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                    //tried ^ this 3 line also.

                    } while ((true));
    clientSocket.Close();
    serverSocket.Stop();
```

Comment: No, this is not weird. TCP is a streaming protocol. One `Send()` does not correspond to one `Receive()`. You need to keep reading, not ignore the value returned by `Receive()` and and keep appending the buffer until you know you received an entire message.

Comment: @CodeCaster It is full data I was received. and keeping read it same data. It will be blocked in normal situation in order to read the data only once.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what you mean by that. This code is broken, you shouldn't use sockets if you don't know what you're doing, but use a higher-level protocol instead like HTTP.

Comment: @CodeCaster these code is simplyfied by posting here, only piece of code on tcpcsocket there. but I edited question easy to understand what I want to ask, could you read it again. thanks much!!!><

Comment: Well the code you show does not cause the behavior you described. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. Don't remove relevant code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Im new here but I dont get what you mean, I readed you given link, and it is match the requirements of minimal, complete and verifiable example. Im very sure there was no other code is implicate on these tcpsocket and client code. Java side is verified sent only once.

Comment: No, it's entirely against the nature of TCP to respond with the same packet over and over again. The code you show will not repeat the last message.

Comment: That's a pretty valid question today I faced exactly the same behavior. and still cannot figure out why is it happening.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im found what is the problem after a day investigate.

but its still weird:

*on Java Client*:

```
socket.close();//<--here causing a start of server read same last data infinitly
```

it was not closing it properly. maybe where protocol is still **close_wait** state to ensure all packets is arrived to server?

.

*fake resolve*:

Im write my own command packets send to server like "cmd_request_close_connection", and close the connection on server side when server receive packet like this.

Comment: my own answer is accept my self tomorrow if no other best answer to explain how problem persist.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that the receiver is ignoring end of stream. CLOSE_WAIT has nothing to do with it either, except that it proves that the server is ignoring EOS.

Answer (score 0):

The server is ignoring the count returned by `Receive()`. It is therefore (a) ignoring endi of stream and (b) processing invalid data in the buffer.